# How to remove drawableleft

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a button and a text-view, text-view has a drawable-left.
After click on button the drawable-left should be removed and a plain text should be set to Text-view, but I don’t know how to remove drawable-left from code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

The `drawableLeft` (or any of the similar attributes) XML attribute can be modified (*removing a `drawable` in your case*) via code using something like this:

```
yourTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
yourTextView.setText("The Text You Need In There");
```

The constructor for the method is in this order:

```
setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
```

Read more about the method [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 31):

We can sets the **Drawables** (if any) to appear to the **left of, above, to the
   right of, and below** the text.

***Use 0 or null if you do not want a Drawable there.***

```
 textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

The Drawables' bounds will be set to their intrinsic bounds.

Calling this method will overwrite any Drawables previously set using
     `{@link #setCompoundDrawablesRelative}` or related methods.

And if we wants to **set Drawables** then we can use :

```
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.smiley, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 15):

The drawables of a `TextView` can be set programatically via the [setCompoundDrawables](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawables%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) method.

So you could try this:

```
textView.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, null);
```

Or

```
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 13):

### Add a Kotlin Extension

If you are going to be doing this frequently, adding an extension makes your code more readable

```
fun TextView.clearDrawables() {
    this.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0)
}
```

To use the extension, simply call

```
view.clearDrawables()
```

Answer (score 1):

How to do this and apply to any of the four drawables with `DataBinding`

```
@BindingAdapter(value = [
"leftDrawable",
"topDrawable",
"rightDrawable",
"bottomDrawable"], requireAll = false)
fun setCompoundDrawables(textView: TextView,
                     @DrawableRes left: Int?,
                     @DrawableRes top: Int?,
                     @DrawableRes right: Int?,
                     @DrawableRes bottom: Int?) {

textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
    left ?: 0,
    top ?: 0,
    right ?: 0,
    bottom ?: 0
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Set All Position is Zero Your Drawable item is remove**

**Its Working Using This setOnFocusChangeListener method**

**et_feedback.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0, 0, 0);**

```
et_feedback.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                //TODO using this Drawable icon remomve  onclick
                et_feedback.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0, 0, 0);
                et_feedback.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            }
        });
```